# Mejorar la velicidad creando columnas dinamicas en un Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Estoy creando un Dataframe con la siguiente informacion:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from time import time

start_time = time()

columns = 60

Data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=(700000, 3)), columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
Data['f'] = (Data.index % 60) + 1
Data['column_-1'] = 100
for i in range(columns):
    Data['column_' + str(i)] = np.where(  # Condicion 1
        Data['f'] == 1,
        1000 + i,
        np.where(  # Condicion 2
            i < Data['f'],
            0,
            np.where(  # Condicion 3
                Data['a'] > Data['b'],
                Data['column_' + str(-1)] * Data['c'],
                Data['column_' + str(-1)]
            )
        )
    )

elapsed_time = time() - start_time
print("Elapsed time: %.10f seconds." % elapsed_time)
```

**Elapsed time: 1.0710000992 seconds.**

quiero saber si hay una mejor forma de hacerlo, generando las columnas dinamicamente y mejorando la velocidad del script, gracias.